# How to build a form where variables have dependence in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I notice that in Google Colab one can use a form to build a interactive widget for tuning hyper-parameters. However, all the examples are forms with independent variables.

Suppose I have two variables `x_max`, and `x_init`, where `x_max` can be chosen from a dropdown with choices `[1,2,3]`, and `x_init` is chosen from a slider with range `0` to `x_max`?

Can I do this in Google Colab?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that possible.

But you can achieve the same result by using something like this

- `x_max` chosen from dropdown.
- `factor` as slider from 0.0 to 1.0
- `x_init = factor * x_max`

Comment: Yes you are right, as for numerical values you can always reparameterize them to decouple. But actually in my case the final goal is (1) choose model mode from a dropdown; (2) dynamically generate a form consisting all hyper parameters of the model associated to the chosen mode. I hope these function or support of `ipywidgets` can be added to Colab in the future.

Comment: ipywidgets isn't fully supported but they provide a mechanism to call js from python and vice version. So, if you really want to, you can implement it yourself. I did make some simple UIs which work similarly myself.